# Can Shor‘s code correct two- or three-qubit errors?

Tags: error-correction

I have read some articles about Shor's code (e.g. [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2794)). It is said that Shor's code can correct a single-qubit error. What about two qubit errors? Three qubit errors? It confused me a lot...

Comment: +1 and welcome to the community! We hope to see much more of you here in the future! As for the close vote and downvote, they were by someone else, but I suspect that you might your questions would get a more positive response if you used complete sentences, rather than sentence fragments like "Three qubit errors?", or the problem is that you talk about "single errors" and "single-qubit errors" like they're the same thing. A single 3-qubit error is still a single error. Anyway, hopefully the answer by Adam was useful!

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can combine weaker codes to obtain stronger codes using concatenation (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9608012) or chapter X B in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2794)).

Suppose we have a quantum error correcting code that encodes a logical qubit into $n$ physical qubits. Let $d$ denote the code distance, i.e. the smallest number of qubits we must act on with a local Pauli operator in order to induce a non-trivial logical transformation on the code subspace. Similarly to the case of classical codes, if an error affects no more than $t=\big\lfloor\frac{d-1}{2}\big\rfloor$ qubits the decoder can diagnose the error correctly.

Now, we can use the code to encode $n$ logical qubits in $n^2$ physical qubits and then we can add a second level of encoding to encode a second-level logical qubit into the $n$ first-level logical qubits. Then the smallest number of qubits we must act on with a local Pauli operator in order to induce a non-trivial logical transformation on the code subspace is $d'=d^2$. Consequently, the two-level concatenated code can correct any

$$
t'=\bigg\lfloor\frac{d'-1}{2}\bigg\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor\frac{d^2-1}{2}\bigg\rfloor
$$

physical errors and if $d>1$ then $t'>t$. For example, the two level Shor's code can correct any four physical errors.

Concatenation can be continued to any number of levels and if the physical error rate is low enough it allows us to bring the logical error rate below any desired target value. This last result is known as the [threshold theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_threshold_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So if we have two qubits errors, we need to combine two 9-qubits shor's code as a whole system?

Comment: Yes, if you'd like to be able to recover from errors on any two physical qubits, then one way is to use two-level concatenated Shor's code. Note that this is excessive in the sense that it can actually recover from errors on any three physical qubits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So if I just have a 9 qubits Shor's code (only), I cannot correct 2 qubits errors. But if one is phase error and the other one is flip error, the 9 qubits shor's code can complete. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, if one error is a bit-flip and the other is a phase-flip then we can correct them using the 9-qubit Shor's code. However, if the first error is a bit-flip on the first qubit and the second error is a bit-flip on the second qubit, then we can't correct them. The point is that with 9 qubit Shor's code we cannot correct *arbitrary* two-qubit errors - we have to get lucky. However, we have a *guarantee* that we can correct *arbitrary* $t=1$ qubit errors. Similarly, with two levels of concatenation we have a guarantee that we can correct arbitrary $t=3$ qubit errors - no need for luck :-)

Comment: Note also that sometimes you can get *really lucky* and multiple errors make no change to the quantum state at all. For example, a phase-flip on the first and a phase-flip on the second qubit together do nothing at all in 9-qubit Shor's code.

Comment: Hi, @Adam Thank you for your kind explanation! However, I am still confused about how to concatenate two of Shor's code for two-qubit errors. I tried to prove that but I think my answer is not correct. I read the paper but they didn't mention that. Could you give me some details about that?

Comment: The logical $|0_L\rangle$ of the (one-level, i.e. "unconcatenated") Shor's code is $(|000\rangle+|111\rangle)(|000\rangle+|111\rangle)(|000\rangle+|111\rangle)/\sqrt{8}$. The logical $|0_{LL}\rangle$ of the two-level concatenated Shor's code is $(|0_L0_L0_L\rangle+|1_L1_L1_L\rangle)(|0_L0_L0_L\rangle+|1_L1_L1_L\rangle)(|0_L0_L0_L\rangle+|1_L1_L1_L\rangle)/\sqrt{8}$. Similarly, for the $|1_L\rangle$ state. In other words, you replace physical qubits with encoded qubits which adds a level.

Comment: @AdamZalcman I thought the two-level Shor code has a code distance $d^2$ where $d=3$ so it can correct arbitrary $\lfloor (d^2-1)/2 \rfloor = 4$ errors? but your analysis only gives $3$, not the strongest condition. what happened? (see e.g. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/31819/concatenated-quantum-code)

Comment: My answer was wrong. Thank you for catching! The error was in the assumption that decoding is done _independently_ at each level. This is suboptimal. One way to see this is to consider the structure of the stabilizer group of the concatenated code and notice that the measurements of its generators provide _more information_ that the measurements of the generators of the stabilizer groups of all first level logical qubits.

Comment: For example, the stabilizer group of Shor's code has $8$ generators, so $9$ independent instances of it have $72$ generators altogether. However, the stabilizer group of two-level Shor's code has $80$ generators. The additional $8$ generators provide extra information that the decoder can use to disambiguate errors like $X_1$ and $X_2X_3$ that are indistinguishable with a single level of concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

Shor's code is specifically designed to correct all possible single-qubit errors. There are some two-qubit errors that it can correct for (e.g. Pauli $X$ on one qubit and Pauli $Z$ on another). You will also be able to find specific combinations of multiple-qubit errors for which it can correct, but those will be the exception rather than the rule. Instead, if you want to protect against two-qubit errors, you employ different strategies - either code concatenation, or just find a different error correcting code with a larger distance.

Comment: Thank you so much! That means if qubit 1 has an X error and qubit 2 has a Z error, the shor's code can correct it. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Any X error together with any Z error (including X and Z errors on the same qubit, i.e. a Y error) can be corrected in the 9-qubit Shor's code.

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide a sketch proof for why it cannot detect 2 qbit errors:
Let's define two different 2 qubits errors one will be applied on the state 0 and the other on the state 1.
If we show that
$$
    E_1 0_s = E_2 1_s
$$ This proves that Shor's encoding cannot correct 2 qubit errors.

Now we can find such errors:

$E_1 = Z$ on the first Qbit meaning $Z \otimes I \otimes ... \otimes I$

$E_2 = Z$ on the fourth and seventh Qbits meaning $ I \otimes I \otimes I \otimes Z \otimes I \otimes I \otimes Z \otimes I \otimes I$

you can do the and you'll get that $E_1 \neq E_2$ however $E_1 |0\rangle_s = E_2 |1\rangle_s$

Answer (score 1):

The distance 3 Shor code can't correct 2 errors. There are pairs of errors that have symptoms that look identical to a single error, but require different corrections.

However, the distance 5 Shor code can correct 2 errors.

Comment: The code can't correct _all_ weight-2 errors, but it can correct _some_ of them. For example it can correct $X_1X_4$. Also, the syndrome of $X_1X_4$ is different from the syndrome of every weight-1 error. I'm using stabilizer generators $Z_1Z_2$, $Z_2Z_3$, $Z_4Z_5$, $Z_5Z_6$, $Z_7Z_8$, $Z_8Z_9$, $X_1X_2X_3X_4X_5X_6$ and $X_4X_5X_6X_7X_8X_9$.